# why my script codes cant add a class to my object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem about `.addClass` in my scripts.
I linked the jquery.js.
I dont know why my code can't add class to my `li`?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-text ul li#1').addClass('active');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-text">
 <ul>
  <li id="1">Cars 3</li>
  <li id="2">Your Name</li>
  <li id="3">Lion King</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the HTML already there when the script runs?

Comment: Hi, i tried your code and works for me.

Comment: It works for me. Note, however, that id's should be unique within the context of the document. Perhaps you have more than one element with `id="1"`?

Comment: have you defined the active class in css ? it does add the active class to the html, with your above code.

Answer (score 0):

Id names should always start with a character. Having numeric IDs will cause problems. Not sure whether that *is* the problem here, but I suspect it. Better use IDs like `id="i1"` for your `<li>`s.

Comment: I am amazed how quickly you can downvote! The answer was only online for 5 seconds before it was downvoted! Respect! Can you also tell me why?

Comment: While I agree as a rule of good practice, as of HTML5, id's can start with a number and be valid. (CSS still doesn't support that, though, but HTML5 does.)

Comment: This is just a comment but it was posted as an answer to the question. Although if you're certain this is the problem, you could expand a bit?

Comment: @Andrew This is the answer! and helped the OP. You can see his thoughts on the his answer. Why SO became a place for people to talk down on others on every single situation possible. No wonder why SO is going down! Have some respect.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian - I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not talking down to anyone at all. This is a helpful comment but not an answer. It could easily be made into an answer, though, especially given that it helped the OP successfully.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Speculation as to the problem is not an answer. Furthermore, nobody could've known this comment solved the problem, not until OP posted a new answer stating that it solved the problem. Once again, I never talked down to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code absolutely works, no need to start an ID with a number. This was true 10 years ago, but for modern browsers you don't have this restriction anymore.

So I guess your problem is somewhere else, maybe jquery is not included?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-text ul li#1').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-text">
 <ul>
  <li id="1">Cars 3</li>
  <li id="2">Your Name</li>
  <li id="3">Lion King</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> I'd names should always start with a character. Having numeric IDs will cause problems. Not sure whether that is the problem here, but I suspect it. Better use IDs like id="i1" for your
>
> s.

this works